# Osquery custom path installation windows, Is there a way to modify the paths for "Pidfile" and "osquery.db"?

Tags: osquery

I'm attempting to install osquery in a custom location by placing the osqueryd.exe file from my default osquery installation into `C:\Program Files\Test\foo\testosqueryd.exe.` However, when I install it at this location with the flag `--database_path="C:\Program Files\Test\foo\osquery.db"`, it generates an error when attempting to start osquery:

```
Windows could not start the osqueryd service on the local computer.
Error 1067: The process terminates unexpectedly.
```

On the other hand, when I don't use the `--database_path` flag, osquery works, but it creates the osquery folder at the default location `C:\Program Files\osquery\osquery.db`.

My intention is to have the database at a custom location using the `--database_path` flag.How can I achieve this without encountering the error?

Comment: This has nothing to do with rocksdb.

Answer (score 2):

Osquery does support running with an alternate database path and pidfile. And those options are `--database_path` and `--pidfile`. It also supports the `--verbose` argument to increase log output.

The error you provided is **not** from osquery. That is an error from windows saying osquery did not start. If you want to diagnose the issue, you need to find the osquery logs.

But, your example is `--database_path= C:\Program Files\Test\foo\osquery.db`, and I suspect there are two issues. First, you should not have a space after the `=`. Second, you need to quote the path because `Program Files` has a space in it. The syntax for quoting paths on windows is different in powershell, cmd.exe, and service manager configuration.

Lastly, it looks like you renamed `osqueryd.exe` to `testosqueryd.exe`. Osquery can be sensitive to it's file naming, this is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for the response it is helpful. In my actual flags it is correct. There is no space after =  and also path is in double quotes. 
But same concept of custom installation of osquery I did in Linux and Mac os it works there perfectly. Is it limitation of osquery for windows only?

Comment: This is supported on windows. It is probably quoting. Where is this being specified? I don't have an example, but my memory is quoting spaces through sc.exe was quite hard.

As a test, could you try a path without spaces?

Comment: Worked. I was not giving --pidfile

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out